# Extendsript - Adobe Illustrator - Change Character Font Family/Style for each word inside TextFrame by <b>text in bold</b> and <i>text in italic</>

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to import text through the variables window in Illustrator and have javascript for recognize html tags.  and

For exemple (texts with html tags):

> **Préparation** à base de basilic et d’huile de **tournesol**,
> aromatisée.  Ingrédients : Basilic frais 41%, huile de tournesol, eau,
> GRANA PADANO AOP (LAIT, OEUF) 5%, flocons de pommes de terre, sucre,
> sel, farine de *NOIX DE CAJOU* (FRUITS A COQUES), arôme naturel
> (LAIT), acidifiant : acide lactique, pignons de pin 0,5%, antioxydant
> : **acide ascorbique**, ail, arôme naturel de basilic. Peut
> contenir : *arachides*.

Text became :
[text with bold and italic font style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k04j.png)

I do that but it doesn't work

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var textObj = doc.selection[0]; // Assurez-vous que le texte est sélectionné

if (textObj && textObj instanceof TextFrame) {
    var textContent = textObj.contents;

    // Remplace <b> par le style gras
    textContent = textContent.replace(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g, function(match, p1) {
        return p1 ? p1 : match;
    });

    // Remplace <i> par le style italique
    textContent = textContent.replace(/<i>(.*?)<\/i>/g, function(match, p1) {
        return p1 ? p1 : match;
    });

    // Applique le texte modifié à l'objet texte
    textObj.contents = textContent;

    // Applique le style gras avec une police spécifique
    textObj.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = app.textFonts.getByName("MyriadPro-Bold");

    // Applique le style italique avec une police spécifique
    // Remplacez "MyriadPro-It" par la police italique de votre choix
    textObj.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = app.textFonts.getByName("MyriadPro-Cond");

    // Actualise le document
    doc.selection = null;
}
```

it does not recognize changes in  or  tags
It sets all text to BOLD or ITALIC